# Launching Java .class with External Libraries in Terminal

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I've looked around and nothing has solved my problem.

I'm trying to launch a .class file within terminal while including another directory. This is how I'm doing it:

```
java -cp lib/*:bin/ org.package.file
```

However I keep getting an error essentially stating that I'm not including the `lib` directory.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
```

The file is `bin/org/package/file` and I need to include the entire `lib` directory.

I'm doing this in Terminal on an Ubuntu OS.

Comment: what's the exact error that you are getting? And form which directory are you running java command?

Comment: @SMA `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists` - Directory is the one both `lib` and `bin` are in.

Comment: where is your guava*jar in classpath? Try to include it.

Comment: @SMA that's inside the `lib` directory

Comment: No you will need to specify each jar individually like `java -cp lib/Guava.jar:bin/ org.package.file`

Comment: @SMA That worked! But it led me to another different error... PROGRESS! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify individual libraries in the command line to specify the classpath rather than using wildcard like:

```
java -cp lib/a.jar:lib/b.jar:bin/ org.package.file
```

From the looks of it, you do have guava jar in your lib directory, so try to include all the jar's in your lib directory like above and that should resolve your issue.